# Javascript remove last occurance of substring from string

Tags: javascript

I have a string `str` and a string `substr`.

I want to remove the last occurance of `substr` from `str`.

```js
var str = "foo bar foo bar";
var substr = "foo";
str = str.removeLast(substr);
```

to leave `str` as

```
foo bar  bar
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: With [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [`.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()` to achieve this:

```js
function removeLast(haystack, needle) {
  const idx = haystack.lastIndexOf(needle);
  return haystack.slice(0, idx) + haystack.slice(idx + needle.length);
}
```

Note: This function assumes that `needle` is always a substring of `haystack`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```js
var res = "foo bar foo bar".split(" ");
res.splice(res.reverse().findIndex(a => a === "foo"), 1);
console.log(res.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help....

```js
var str = "foo bar foo bar";
var substr = "foo";

var sub = str.slice(0,3);
str =str.replaceAll("foo ","")
#console.log(str);
#console.log(sub);
console.log(sub+" "+str);
```